# Mbtiles to plot in map using react-leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mbtiles, react

I am new to map technology and I am using react-leaflet to plot GEOJSON to map. It was all going well but then I m facing load time with massive GeoJSON data, so need to convert GeoJSON to mbtiles. With the help of Tippecanoe I successfully converted GeoJSON to mbtiles.

Now the problem is how to plot those mbtiles in a map using react-leaflet. I used the TileLayer component to plot the map and worked on different methods to plot mbtiles using the TileLayer component of react-leaflet, but result is none.

Here is code snippet i tried to display tiles in react-leaflet:

```
<div className="map-section">
    <MapContainer
        style={{ height: "550px" }}
        center={this.state.location}
        zoom={this.state.zoom}
        minZoom="11"
    >
        <TileLayer
            url={process.env.PUBLIC_URL+"/mapdata/ward1.mbtiles"}
        />
    </MapContainer>
</div>
```

Comment: There are no client side JS solutions to display mbtiles. You either have to set up a server that will use mbtiles to serve .pbf tiles, or you can use tippecanoe `-e` option to directly create .pbf tiles and then put those on the server. For displaying .pbf tiles you then need a plugin like https://github.com/mhasbie/react-leaflet-vectorgrid.

Comment: Hi @TomazicM, thank you so much for the response. I tried react-leaflet-vectorgrid as you have given github link. I installed it and while running another problem I faced as follow :
×
TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
in /node_modules/react-leaflet-vectorgrid/dist/react-leaflet-vectorgrid.min.js:858

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with React I can't help you here.